# Reordering rows in a tableview and saving the order after reloading or closing the app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, nsuserdefaults

I have a tableview and I would like the user to be able to move the cells in whichever order they would like. The cells are objects that are pulled from a database in the backend, so when the user reloads or closes the app, the order they changed the cells does not stay, and it keeps grabbing the same order that they were added to the app in. I tried to save this into UserDefaults, the app crashes with the message

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object (
    "Myapp.Animal",
    "Myapp.Animal",
    "Myapp.Animal"
) for key sortedanimals'
```

I understand that I cannot save the entire object to UserDefaults, but I am confused and unaware on how I can save only the order to the UserDefaults.

These are the tableview functions where the user can drag the cells in the tableview:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider())
    dragItem.localObject = allAnimals[indexPath.row]
    return [ dragItem ]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {
    let mover = allAnimals.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    allAnimals.insert(mover, at: to.row)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(allAnimals, forKey:"sortedanimals") //this is where the app crashes,
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
    
}
```

My backend code does not tell the frontend to set the cells in any specific order, it is just defaulting to grabbing them in the order of id (or the order they were added to the app in)

I have looked around stackoverflow, but can not find any questions where they are trying to reorder data coming from the backend, only reordering data that is created inside of the frontend. Is this even possible with UserDefaults?

Edit:

I have now created an array that lists all of the object ids in the order they were re organized into. I am however unaware of how to reorganize the data retrieved from the backend into the order I would like it to be ordered by. This is the array I have created. Would I need to send this array to the backend to reorganize, or would I do this in frontend?

```
let ids = allAnimals.map { $0.id }
```

Comment: You have to add an index or an unique identifier to the model. Then save this and sort the items by index or uuid. Saving entire objects which are refetched anyway makes no sense

Comment: You say that the objects have an `id`. Assuming this is just an Int or a string, you can save an array of these to UserDefaults and then use that to sort the data you retrieve from the back end.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I have created an array of each object id in the order they were reorganized into. What would be my next step to sorting the data I retrieve from the backend?